# Find intersection of two cell arrays in mATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two cell arrays C & D , they contains numerical data (but some cells are empty) . the data that is inside each cell may be a 2D array, I want to find the intersection of each cell in C with each cell in D 
 How can I do such thing?

for example : if the size of C & D is 10-by10 
C= [ {1 2 } ,{ 3  4},.... etc]
D = [ { 1 34 7} , {2 5},... etc]

Out = c intersect D 
out= [ { 1} , {},.... etc]

Comment: I am not exactly sure how your data looks like and also not exactly sure what "find the intersection of each cell in C with each cell in D" really means. Can you share the matlab code of a simple example for ``C`` and ``D`` with all important features as well as the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

```
>> C = {1 [2 3 4; 5 6 7] [] [] 5};
>> D = {1:2 3:5 6 7:9 []};
>> R = cellfun(@(c, d) intersect(c(:), d(:)), C, D, 'uniformoutput', 0);
>> R{:}
ans =
     1
ans =
     3
     4
     5
ans =
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
ans =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-1
ans =
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is only numeric (each cell contains a numeric value and empties) I suggest you to change that to a numeric array and use the `intersect` function. It is easy to represent missing values as `NaN`.

To convert to double:

```
tmp = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, []};
% // Getting rid of the empties 
index_empties = cellfun(@isempty, tmp);
tmp(index_empties) = {NaN};

% // converting to double
tmp_double = cellfun(@double, tmp);
```

Cell values are there to easily create a vector with non-homogeneous data types (Strings and numbers, for example). It is quite common see people using cells to store numbers. While this might be valid in some cases, using cells to store homogeneous data will waste memory and will complicate some operations. For example, you cannot easily sum two cell-vectors with numeric data while summing two double-vectors is trivial.

Comment: @joanna The importance of providing enough details :)